# WebStorm class to className

Tags: reactjs, ide, webstorm

Recently I updated my WebStorm app and my settings been restored. Now when I write `.row` and pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> I get `div` with attribute `class="row"` instead of `className="row"`.

Which setting is responsible for that? Need to make it like it was before update.